# Hybrid App development - iOS, Android, Windows Phone AND Desktop?

Tags: c#, angularjs, visual-studio, hybrid, ionic-framework

I'm developing an application on my own that i want to run as a Web App, and on iOS, Android, Windows Phone and as a desktop application.

The easiest way I can see to achieve this is to develop a hybrid app in visual studio in Angular/Ionic so that will take care of the mobile devices.

For the desktop app I was intending on creating a C# application that acted as a container for a web control then simply deploy the HTML/JS/CSS in with it. Obviously i'll replace Ionic with Bootstrap for the layout but it means I can keep 90% of the JS code between apps saving me a lot of time.

The reason I need a native desktop app is that it needs access to WCF to communicate with other parts of the suite.

I've looked at Metro Apps but they're horrific, having a business application that demands full screen isn't gonna be any good. I know there are options for "fixing" metro apps but it still doesn't give the everything I need(like being able to minimize to tray & WCF)

Is this the workflow that you'd expect or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: What are the use cases for the various platforms?

Comment: Hi Grav, briefly the mobile/web app is to give access to information that is submitted by other uses while the we're away from our PC. The desktop app is the only thing that is submitting information which it receives from communication with a word addin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not build your app as single page web application to begin with, using Angular.js and Bootstrap (it is the "mobile first" framework after all)? Run same app, with minor changes, on iOS, Android and Windows Phone using [Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/). For Windows Desktop, have a WinForms/WPF "frame" and embedded Chromium browser ([CEF Sharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp) or [CEF glue](https://bitbucket.org/fddima/cefglue)).

Comment: Awesome, thanks for that I was mainly worried that I was taking the right path, but yes I was intending on "framing" the browser in a C# and then making the relevant calls from JS within the page using window.external.myFunction

Comment: Thanks for that, looks like I over complicated things a little there!

Comment: Prepare for headache though, what seems easy when you read about it is usually a little more complicated when you start implementing...

Comment: Heh well so far its panning out good, the handy bit is the desktop is about is only a bit bigger than an iPhone 5 screen so in terms of the layout its not too much headache.

I'm a bit concerned about the container working properly but we'll see!

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing for an enterprise environment, you should be prepared to face old versions (less than 9) of Internet Explorer rendering your WebView in the desktop application. Depending on your use of html5 specific things this might be a problem.

Aside from that, your workflow sounds reasonable, although I'm wondering how you access your WCF-Service on the mobile devices without any platform specific code and why that way isn't suitable for the desktop application?

Comment: The flow is like so, desktop versions pick up the data via word addins and filesystem watchers etc, when one of these methods finds something we're interested in it tells the desktop client "Hey you need to submit this to Mr Webservice". The API then sets adds these events to an "inbox" so mobile, tablet and web clients can simply access/receive notifications on that inbox

Comment: Oh and in terms of HTML i'm using Ionic(for mobile)/Bootstrap(desktop), as I understand it the version used to render these would be the control that I deploy rather than the OS particular one?

Comment: I thought that you use some graphics framework (bootstrap in this case) and some javascript business logic to basically create a html file with some assets and then create a native app, that renders the html (and provides some additional apis). Rendering html usually means useing the WebView control (or WebBrowser in WPF). On Windows this means, that the installed Version of the Internet Explorer will render the page.
So yes, you deploy the control (html) and use a control (native) provided by the OS for your native app.